# Proper Data Structure for Commentable Comments

Tags: c#, sql, database-design

Been struggling with this on an architectural level.

I have an object which can be commented on, let's call it a `Post`. Every post has a unique ID.

Now I want to comment on that Post, and I can use ID as a foreign key, and each PostComment has an ItemID field which correlates to the Post. Since each Post has a unique ID, it is very easy to assign "Top Level" comments.

When I comment on a comment however, I feel like I now need a PostCommentComment, which attaches to the ID of the PostComment. Since ID's are assigned sequentially, I can no longer simply use ItemID to differentiate where in the tree the comment is assigned. I.E. both a Post and a Post Comment might have an ID of '5', so my foreign key relationship is invalid.

This seems like it could go on infinitely, with PostCommentCommentComment's etc...

What's the best way to solve this? Should I have a field in the comment called "IsPostComment" or something of the like to know which collection to attach the ID to? This strikes me as the best solution I've seen so far, but now I feel like I need to make recursive DataBase calls which start to get expensive.

Meaning, I get a `Post` and get all PostComments `where ItemID == Post.ID && where IsPostComment == true`

Then I take that as a collection, gather all the ID's of the `PostComments`, and do another search `where ItemID == PostComment[all].ID && where IsPostComment == false`, then repeat infinitely.

This means I make a call for every layer, and if I'm calling 100 Posts, I might make 1000 DB calls to get 10 layers of comments each.

What is the *right* way to do this?

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/162685/7043).

Comment: @delnan Wasn't sure which was the right place to post this after surfing META. I'll delete the other post, as this is the more productive dialog.

Comment: Has nothing to do with sharepoint or specificially sharepoint2010 (had these as tags, removing...)

Comment: It's being used in SharePoint and being stored in Lists, but I thought it was a more general design topic, aka how to create a tree in a DB properly.

Comment: If this is the case, then your last sentence "if I'm calling 100 Posts, I might make 1000 DB calls" is an underestimate :-)

Comment: Yeah. I have a CAML generator that works well for things like this. Can essentially create a large OR tree that translates well into SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you would just have PostComment, not PostCommentComment or anything beyond that.

All PostComments have a PostId, so when you load comments for that post, you just query by PostId.

All comments also have ParentId, which points to another comment (top-level comments will not have a ParentId). In this way, every comment can have comments on it to any depth, but the data remains flat in the database.

Once you load all comments with a given PostId, you can assemble the tree/hierarchy in memory using the ParentId property.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was thinking (though I don't have much experience with database design).  I was thinking, though, why not also store which comment thread ID, and a DepthInThread int with each comment?  Then you wouldn't even have to sort the comments in memory, and could just push them directly into the site.

Comment: @RobertChrist If that optimization works for your system, sure. A couple of things to consider, if a comment has a parent, children, and grandchildren, to what thread ID does it belong? Do they all belong to the original comment? Knowing that a grandchild belongs to a thread probably isn't enough to avoid in-memory sorting; you still have to resolve the parent under which it should appear. Also, if you use something like `DepthInThread`, you should account for the possibility that you will have gaps in the sequence if a comment is deleted/flagged/removed.

Answer (score 3):

I would only have one table, named `Post`.

```
CREATE TABLE Post
(
    PostID int PK,
    PostContent nvarchar,
    ParentPostID int FK null,
    ...
)
```

A post will have and ID, post content, and whatever other fields you need. It will also have a ParentPostID, which is `nullable` and foreign key's to `PostID`. If the `ParentPostID` is `null`, you know it is the original post. If there is a parent, you know the post is a comment. This allows you to have comments nested as deep as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all comments in the same table structure and use the same ID sequence. Then:

1. Use `COMMENT_DEPTH` field to indicate the recursion level.For example a postComment has `COMMENT_DEPTH=0` where as a comment on postComment has `COMMENT_DEPTH=1`.
2. Also use a `PARENT_COMMENT` field. That should be null for comments that have `COMMENT_DEPTH=0` and it should contain parent comment ID if `COMMENT_DEPTH>0`.

This will even enable you to have multiple levels of comment. Moreover, you can get post comments by:

```
WHERE COMMENT_DEPTH=0
```

and you can comments on a comment A by:

```
WHERE PARENT_COMMENT=A.ID AND COMMENT_DEPTH=A.COMMENT_DEPTH+1
```